# Согласование в числе

Tags: согласование, число

*Половина его волос были золотыми, а половина – серебряными*
или *Половина его волос была золотой, а половина – серебряной*?

*Вернул народу все, что у них отобрали* или *Вернул народу все, что у него отобрали*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Половина его волос были золотыми, а половина – серебряными.**

Половина, часть – это лишь существительные с собирательным значением, поэтому именно **волосы были золотыми или серебряными**.

У Розенталя есть подобные примеры (использование мн. числа при согласовании): http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm

...при обратном согласовании, если именная часть составного сказуемого имеет форму множественного числа, например: **Большинство людей,** встретившихся мне здесь, **были оборванные и полураздетые.**.. (Л. Толстой);

2) **Вернул народу все, что у него отобрали.**

Местоимение ***у него*** соответствует существительному ***народ*** в значении ***трудовая масса,*** а не в значении ***люди.***

НАРОД, -а; м. 3. только ед. Основная трудовая масса населения страны. Трудовой н. Борьба народа за свои права. 4. только ед.; род.: -а (-у). Люди. Огромная толпа народу. В театре было мало народа.

Answer (score 2):

**Половина его волос была золотой, а половина – серебряной**. Воображение рисует человека, у которого полголовы золотого цвета, другая половина – серебряного.

**Половина его волос были золотыми, а половина – серебряными.** Представляется  человек, у которого на голове вперемежку расположены волосы золотого и серебряного цвета.

**Вернул народу все, что у него отобрали.** Отобрали у народа в целом.
Альтернативный вариант: **Вернул людям все, что у них отобрали.**